# Installing mysql-dev packages on openSuse 11.1

Tags: mysql, installation, opensuse

I'm trying to get the Ruby mysql gem installed and running.  The installation of this gem requires the presence and availability of mysql dev libraries.

mysql --version tells me I'm running distribution 5.0.67.

The box is openSUSE 11.1.  I am marginally familiar with the apt-get package manager.  My first attempts to get the dev packages installed were:

```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package libmysqlclient-dev
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to go from here.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten Suse installs generally use yast.  I was able to locate and install the mysql dev libraries from /sbin/yast2.